# Timestamp sem utilizar os.time()

Tags: lua

Como converter uma data e tempo no seu timestamp, mas sem utilizar o `os.time()` em Lua? Qual a expressão para calcular? Será que é possível?

Exemplo:

```
data = "01/01/2015"
hora = "10:00:00"
```

Comment: timestamp desde que origem?

Comment: Veja [luatz](https://github.com/daurnimator/luatz).

Answer (score 0):

Bom, de acordo com [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp ] existem vários formatos de TimeStamp, se você já possui as informações de data e hora, como na pergunta, você pode procurar um formato que se encaixa nessa descrição.
Por exemplo, a ISO 8601 [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 ] define que uma data (dia/mes/ano) deve ser representada na forma ano-mes-dia, você poderia usar as funções de string do lua para separar as informações digitadas e gerar esse Time Stamp. Por exemplo, vamos supor que você implemente uma função de split como descrito em [ http://lua-users.org/wiki/SplitJoin ], você poderia gerar seu TimeStamp assim:

```
data = "04/02/2016" --Quatro de Janeiro de 2016
dataTable = split(data,"/")
--timeStamp = 2016-02-04 (Conforme ISO 8601)
timeStamp = dataTable[1] .. "-" ..dataTable[2] .. "-" ..dataTable[3]
```

A Mesma ideia pode ser aplicada para adicionar as horas, minutos e segundos. 
Entretanto, se você quer um time stamp como o retorna por os.time() (Segundos desde uma determinada data), é fortemente recomendado o uso de uma biblioteca, embora seja sim possível calcular, de uma forma bem grosseira ficaria assim:

```
anoZero=1960
ano=2016
mes = 2 + ((ano-anoZero)*12)
dias = 4 + (mes * 30) --Simplificação, o ideal seria calcular o numero de dias para cada mês
horas = 1 + (dias * 24)
minutos=29 + (horas*60)
segundos=minutos * 60 -- Numero de segundos desde 1960-01-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: só um detalhe: "split" não é método nativo da linguagem Lua, tem que ser escrito ou então usado de algum módulo exteno (Penlight, Microlight, etc)